# visual studio 2010 crashing when build happens

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, crash

my part of code is

```
public int MyProperty { set { DoTask(); } }

private void DoTask()
{
    int MyValue = MyProperty;
}
```

I don't have `Get` accessor for `MyProperty`.
I tried to get the value of it in `DoTask()`.
When I build this application in VS2010, it is crashing insted of giving a build Error. Isn't this an error? Correct me if I'm wrong or Misunderstood.

Regards
Umesh C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should clearly NOT cause an infinite loop, as the Getter for MyProperty does not exist (read: not even private). The compiler should detect this.

Nevertheless, a better design would be to provide a public getter for public settable properties.
What your code will do is de-facto calling a method, so why would you even need the property? Simply make your DoTask() method public and let clients call it directly.
Remember, with your code, you had absolutely no chance to get the value of MyProperty, not even from within your class.

Comment: I understood that the way I'm doing is not correct. What I wanted to know is why it is crashing and not showing an build error saying get accessor is not defined

Answer (score 3):

I found issues with code you have written

```
public int MyProperty { set { DoTask(value); } }

private void DoTask(int value)
{
    int MyValue = value;
}
```

or

```
public int MyProperty { set { int MyValue = value; } }
```

you code doesnt making any sense..

Comment: I want to call Dotask when ever someone assigns any value to Myproperty. So I've done this way.But When I try to get that it should give build error instead of Crashing VS.

Answer (score 0):

its clear it causes an infinite loop 
my property calls dotask and dotask calls myporpety
and it crashes the compiler 
the  solution that [Pranay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314488/pranay-rana)provided is good idea try to use

so you should the way define the property
change it to

```
private int m_MyProperty;
public int MyProperty { get {return m_MyProperty}set { DoTask(); m_MyProperty=value} }
```

private void DoTask()
{
    int MyValue = m_MyProperty;
}

DoTask Always reads previos value of MyProperty

Comment: It causes infinite loop if I again assign a value in DoTask(). I'm trying to read it, not assigning a value so infinite loop doesn't come here.   
My doubt was why it is crashing and not showing an build error saying get accessor is not defined

Comment: @Chilaka Umesh, you seem right that this sould not crash the compiler. see my answer about your solution suggestions.

Comment: your are right when i coded on y 2010 compiler i  get this error Error 1 
The property or indexer 
'WindowsFormsApplication23.Form1.MyProperty' 
cannot be used in this context because it lacks 
the get accessor